# How to make a sinusoidal pattern stationary time series?

Tags: python, r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have data which is sinusoidal and want to predict next points of it, so I applied arima model which assumes that that the data should be stationary. I tried to stationarize the data with log-transformation without differencing (because there is no trend) but there still a variation in the variance along the data.

What should I do to turn it to stationary? Or this question is not even good? because I head that stationarity is not a property of sinusoidal patterns.

I would be more grateful if you let me know other predictive models that are worth trying with this data.

Note: The data has multiple-frequency components.

Comment: Is the data seasonal, is that why it is sinusoidal? If so, have you tried doing a seasonal differencing? Here is a good link for Seasonal ARIMA modeling: https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/9

Comment: It's sinusoidal because I'm sure the function is sinusoidal so I'm trying on a theoretical data with cosines with multiple frequencies. So I guess seasonality is not the issue?